# Weird html tags generated for a HTML select element

Tags: html, angularjs

My code:

```
<select ng-model="event-type" id="event-type" required>
    <option value="Marriage" selected>Marriage</option>
    <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
</select>
```

generates under Firebug:

```
<select ng-model="event-type" id="event-type" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
   <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
   <option value="Marriage" selected>Marriage</option>
   <option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help me to understand why this first line has been generated ? Because of that, my first element cannot be selected by default.